# Angle between input voltage and current

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

To calculate the angle between the input voltage and the current, can I combine the reactive powers together and the true powers together to get 2200 VAR and 600 W and then use the power triangle? Or do I have to work out Load 2 and Load 3 separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *can I combine the reactive powers together and the true powers
> together to get 2200 VAR and 600 W*

No, it's slightly more complex than that. Note the (L) and (C) labels in Load_2 and Load_3. This means that some of the load current is lagging (L) and some is leading (C). In effect you need to subtract the two and find the net leading or lagging current. For instance, if both were the same value but one was lagging whilst the other was leading then the two cancel out. However, because the two loads are not ideal inductance nor capacitance, I think it's best breaking each load down to either an RL or an RC series circuit then paralleling them using math.

No short cuts I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you Andy, Can I use the voltage in all calculations to be 100<0? Or will there be a different voltage going through load 2 and load 3? As in my calculations I've gotten the Load 2 current to be 7.3<-74.1 and the Load 3 current to be 15.3<78.7. Are these numbers accurate?

Comment: Load 2 and Load 3 see the same voltage but, it isn't 100 volts because of Load 1. I'm not going to calculate numbers to check your values. If you need a sanity check on numbers, use a simulation tool.

Comment: Which simulation tool do you recommend? I think I've calculated it correctly but am not sure if the angle should be positive or negative. @Andy aka

Comment: [Microcap12 download button](https://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip)